# How say to this joomla module to take me to my SEF url article?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, joomla

This module takes the articles from categories in joomla and displays them like a blog (short of). the problem is when i click on the title it gives a `&view=item&layout=edit&sliderid=1&id=2`. non friendly, and the link opens the article in my home page. how to make it produce the correct SEF link like suppose to do? I use joomla 3 and mod_rewrite is enabled

Here is the code:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
    require_once(JPATH_SITE.DS.'components'.DS.'com_content'.DS.'helpers'.DS.'route.php');

class PBHSourceJcontent {

public $arg;

public function loadFromDB($itemId = -1) {

    $myQuery = 'SELECT 
                i.* 
                FROM #__content as i 
                WHERE 1=1 
                AND i.state = 1';
    if ($itemId < 0 && !empty($this->arg['categories'])) {
        $myQuery .= ' AND i.catid IN (' .implode(',',$this->arg['categories']). ')';
    }
    if ($this->arg['ordering'] == 'random' && !empty($this->arg['loaded_items'])) {
        $myQuery .= ' AND i.id NOT IN ('.implode(',',$this->arg['loaded_items']).')';
    }
    if ($itemId < 0 && !empty($this->arg['ordering'])) {
        switch ($this->arg['ordering']) {
            case 'title_asc': 
                $myQuery .= ' ORDER BY i.title ASC';
                break;
            case 'title_desc': 
                $myQuery .= ' ORDER BY i.title DESC';
                break;
            case 'date_asc': 
                $myQuery .= ' ORDER BY i.publish_up ASC';
                break;
            case 'hits_desc': 
                $myQuery .= ' ORDER BY i.hits DESC';
                break;
            case 'hits_asc': 
                $myQuery .= ' ORDER BY i.hits ASC';
                break;
            case 'article_order': 
                $myQuery .= ' ORDER BY i.ordering ASC';
                break;
            case 'random':
                $myQuery .= ' ORDER BY RAND()';
                break;
            default: 
                $myQuery .= ' ORDER BY i.publish_up DESC';
                break;
        }
    }
    if ($itemId < 0 && !empty($this->arg['items_number'])) {
        $myQuery .= ' LIMIT ' . $this->arg['items_number'];
    }
    if ($itemId < 0 && !empty($this->arg['items_offset']) && $this->arg['items_offset'] > 0 && $this->arg['ordering'] != 'random') {
        $myQuery .= ' OFFSET ' . $this->arg['items_offset'];
    }
    if ($itemId < 0) {
        return DMHData::loadObjectList($myQuery);
    } else {
        $myQuery .= ' AND i.id = ' . $itemId;
        return DMHData::loadObject($myQuery);
    }
}

public function getItemId($item) {

    return $item->id;
}

public function getItemUrl($item) {

    if ($this->arg['previewpopup'] == 'enabled') {
        $myLink = 'href="#" onclick="DMPinboard.getPreview('.$item->id.');return false;"';
    } else {
        $link = 'index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id='.$item->id;
        $link = ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($item->id, $item->catid);
        $myLink = 'href="'.urldecode($link).'"';
    }

    return $myLink;
}

public function getItemTitle($item) {

    if ($this->arg['show_title'] == 'yes') {
        return $item->title;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}

public function getItemImage($item) {

    if ($this->arg['show_image'] == 'fromtext') {
        $myImage = '';
        $output = preg_match( '/<img[^>]+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"][^>]*>/i', $item->introtext, $matches);
        if ($output > 0) {
            $myImage = $matches[1];
        }
        return $myImage;
    } else if($this->arg['show_image'] == 'introimg') {
        $images = json_decode($item->images);
        return $images->image_intro;
    } else if ($this->arg['show_image'] == 'fullimg') {
        $images = json_decode($item->images);
        return $images->image_fulltext;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}

public function getItemIntro($item) {

    if ($this->arg['show_intro'] == 'yes') {
        $outText = str_replace(array("\t","\n","\r","\r\n"),'',strip_tags($item->introtext));
        if (!empty($this->arg['introlength']) && $this->arg['introlength'] > 0) {
            $outText = PBHHtml::shorter($outText, $this->arg['introlength']);
        }
        return $outText;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}

public function getPreviewImage($item) {

    if ($this->arg['show_popup_images'] == 'fromtext') {
        $myImage = '';
        $output = preg_match('/<img[^>]+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"][^>]*>/i', $item->introtext, $matches);
        if ($output > 0) {
            $myImage = $matches[1];
        }
        return $myImage;
    } else if ($this->arg['show_popup_images'] == 'fullimg') {
        $images = json_decode($item->images);
        return $images->image_fulltext;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}

public function getPreviewTitle($item) {

    if ($this->arg['show_popup_title'] == 'linked') {
        $link = 'index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id='.$item->id;
        $link = ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($item->id, $item->catid);
        return '<a href="'.urldecode($link).'">'.$item->title.'</a>';
    } else if ($this->arg['show_popup_title'] == 'yes') {
        return $item->title;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}

public function getPreviewContent($item) {

    if ($this->arg['show_popup_intro'] == 'withoutimg') {
        $outText = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+\>/i', '', $item->introtext);
    } else if($this->arg['show_popup_intro'] == 'yes') {
        $outText = preg_replace_callback('/(src=["\'])([^"\']+)(["\'])/','PBHHtml::checkImgSrc',$item->introtext);
    } else {
        $outText = '';
    }
    if (!empty($this->arg['previewlength']) && $this->arg['previewlength'] > 0) {
        $outText = PBHHtml::truncate_teaser($outText,$this->arg['previewlength']);
    }
    return $outText;
}

public function getPreviewReadmore($item) {

    if ($this->arg['show_popup_articlelink'] == 'yes') {
        $link = 'index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id='.$item->id;
        $link = ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($item->id, $item->catid);
        return '<a href="'.urldecode($link).'">'.JText::_('COM_DMPINBOARD_FRONTEND_READMORE').'</a>';
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}

public function getShareInfo($item) {

    $share = array();
    //---
    $link = 'index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id='.$item->id;
    $link = ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($item->id, $item->catid);
    $share['url'] = urldecode(JUri::base().$link);
    //---
    $share['title'] = $item->title;
    return $share;
}

}

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "opens the article in my homepage"? Also please show what you have in your layout.  You should be using more of the Joomla API to do this (for example your queries) and also explain why you are assigning `$link` two lines in a row in several places.  I'd recommend simply looking at one of the several core modules that includes links to articles and copy the code from there.

Comment: thank you for answering. as in first i am a little newbie with php! ok what i mean is this. lets say i go to a normal category blog and  click on an article, i expect from my browser to direct me to the correct link path to where my artcile is stored ex. www.vgespies.com/stages/id-alias so i want to display my articles there as a child for stages with a SEF ulr i dont know how to command this component to produses SEF urls

Comment: I thought you said you were making a module not a component.  Please clarify that. However no matter what the best option for you is to look at how the core creates SEF urls and do exactly the same thing. It's really hard to know because you have just dumped a lot of code rather than showing the relevant parts of the code. Also please reply to the questions I asked about why you are assigning $link twice and why your queries are like that as well as what you mean by opening in the home page.  Joomla has an API you need to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you mean to output a SEF url in the second part of the `getItemUrl($item)` function.

Simply

```
$link = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id='.$item->id);
```

will do.  However in your question, above your code, you show `&view=item&layout=edit&sliderid=1&id=2` which is not the url in the code below, and will not take you to the article view.